# Add Extra button additional to cancel in Touch Id Alert?

Tags: ios, touch-id

I integrated TouchId in our app, I need to add additional button(Enter PIN) near with cancel button and also trigger event for that button. Is there any option to do that??[image]

Comment: Any answer for above ques?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide text for a fallback button that will show up if the touch ID fails (for localized authentication).  You do this by setting localizedFallbackTitle on the LAContext

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];

// Set text for the localized fallback button.
context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"Enter PIN";
```

The KeychainTouchID sample shows this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html Look in AAPLLocalAuthenticationTestsViewController

When the fallback button is tapped you get LAErrorUserFallback as the Error type in your handler (LAError.UserFallback for swift).